# Python argparse: Does it have to return a list?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to obtain a string of numbers from argparse. It's optional whether or not the argument -n is provided.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-n', nargs=1) # -n is optional but must come with one and only one argument
args = parser.parse_args()
test = args.n
if test != 'None':
    print("hi " + test)
```

The program fails when I do not provide "-n argument", but works fine when I do.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_args_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print("hi " + test) 
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to concatenate `None` and `"hi "`:

```
print("hi", test)
```

or

```
print("hi " + (test or ''))
```

or test if `test` is set to None explicitly:

```
if test is not None:
    print("hi", test)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question from the title, when `nargs` is used, the returned value of `args.n` is a list (even if the `nargs=1` is used). So when only 1 argument is expected, you may decide to not use `nargs` at all to avoid returning a list.

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-n')
args = parser.parse_args()
test = args.n
if test:
    print("hi " + test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "is" when comparing to None. Should look like this:

```
if test is not None:
    print("hi %s" % test)
```